# CSS Margin only works on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web

I have a little website, and I wanted to have no margin by doing:

```html
    <p id="demo" style="margin-block-start:0em;margin-block-end:0em"></p>
```

But the object still has a margin on every browser except chrome. (Chrome on IOS also does not work)
What have I done wrong? I have seen some other problems that were related to some small typos, but I can't find any of that here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-start#Browser_compatibility

Comment: What's wrong with `margin: 0` ?

Comment: try `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`

Comment: This was just the way I learned doing it. I will although do it like this now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply (at the time of writing), this is a CSS Logical Properties and Values Level 1 **experimental property** and is not supported by most browsers or is supported but *behind an "experimental" flag* which is set at an individual user level.

> This is an experimental technology
>   Check the Browser compatibility table carefully before using this in production.
>
> [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-start#Browser_compatibility)

[image]

I would suggest a fallback of `margin:0` pending final acceptance.